# How to make image more iridescent in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

If I have a fully blue image. (Applied solid blue layer on "colour" layer mode) and I want to make the image more iridescent by randomly making some shades different hues of blue how could I do this? For example adding a "brightness and contrast" layer above it makes it change to different hues of blue but not as pronounced or diverse as I want. Thanks and here is an example of iridescent

[image: example]

Comment: Can you link a picture from the Web that you deem "iridescent"?

Comment: to clarify I want to shift all colours past a certain hue to cyan, and all colours over a certain hue to indigo. and keep the middle cobalt.

Comment: I guess your method, or any method involving conflating brightness and hue (e.g. Curves) can approximate an iridescent effect. But note that true iridescence (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iridescence) has the hue shift with illumination/viewing **angle**, and thus would need a 3D model to work from, even for a static 2D image. The brightness of any given pixel (that you work with for your effect) is not directly and solely linked to angle-of-material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fake it a bit in Camera Raw; shifting aquas, blue & purples in different directions.

[image]

I've pushed this way too far just as an example - & the original image was tiny, so it looks a bit rough.
You can actually keep repeating this action to push things further, though it will get a tad "sci-fi" after a while.

Comment: how do you get regular images into camera raw?

Comment: Filter Menu/ Camera RAW Filter... works on pretty much anything [though I've never tested anything other than RGB]

Comment: I found it just as you commented. pretty cool thanks.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up  doing, it gave the best result. Once was enough.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out but I don't mind alternative methods either or if there are any downsides to what I did. I used "Color Range" from select to select the highlights, midtones and shadows and then applied a different blue "colourize" layer to each layer of the image and stacked them in the right order to get the best effect.

Edit: Ended up using the accepted answer's method.

Comment: Can you add your own image result? Would be nice to see what you got with your method.